# I've suffered from unacceptable IMPORT error

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm working with ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm trying tutorial of [face_detector](http://wiki.ros.org/face_detector#Example_with_robots), but I faced a strange IMPORT error.

But I have the right module.

```
import rospy
from people_msgs.msg import PositionMeasurementArray

class FaceDetectClient(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.face_detect_subs = rospy.Subscriber("/face_detector/people_tracker_measurements_array", 
                                                PositionMeasurementArray, self.face_detect_subs_callback)
    self.pos_measurement_array = PositionMeasurementArray()
```

And the error message I've only got is

```
  File "/home/robotics/catkin_ws/src/my_face_detector/scripts/face_detector_client.py", line 4, in <module>
from people_msgs.msg import PositionMeasurementArray
 ImportError: No module named msg

 [ INFO] [1575467542.196464019]: You must subscribe to one of FaceDetector's outbound topics or else it will not publish anything.
[face_detection_client_start_node-2] process has died [pid 26265, exit code 1, cmd /home/robotics/catkin_ws/src/my_face_detector/scripts/face_detector_client.py __name:=face_detection_client_start_node __log:=/home/robotics/.ros/log/3f210cbc-169d-11ea-b72c-07b764ec1d1d/face_detection_client_start_node-2.log].
log file: /home/robotics/.ros/log/3f210cbc-169d-11ea-b72c-07b764ec1d1d/face_detection_client_start_node-2*.log
```

Because when I run some other packages in `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/` directory (and also people_msgs package is in `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/`, it ran with any problem, I think it is not related to ros path.

If you happen to give me any advice, would you please let me know?

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339173/i%27ve-suffered-from-unacceptable-import-error/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-12-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-12-05**:
Do you using some alternative python install like `anaconda`? This usually lead to some quite strange errors, as the ROS packages don't typically end up in the respective python paths those alternative installs use.

You can try to set the shebang of the script explicitely to `/usr/bin/python2.7` (or wherever your python2.7 executable is located) and check if it works then (keep the ROS env sourced, though!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tested your code and it works for me (at least the import part).

I put some suggestions below:

source your ros setup

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

check that people_msgs pkg is recognized by your setup:

```
rospack list | grep people_msgs
```

should give as result:

```
people_msgs /opt/ros/kinetic/share/people_msgs
```

if not, then install it:

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-people-msgs
```

This should solve your issue. Again, it works on my machine.

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2019-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2019-12-04**:
Thanks for your quick reply. I tried it following your comment, and although I got the message;`people_msgs /opt/ros/kinetic/share/people_msgs`, it still returns `import error` and really depresses me more and more.
How did you do?
I did just `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-people-msgs` and `sudo apt-get install tos-kinetic-face-detector` and the `ImportError` never go away.